# What was the origin of mlecchas according to Hindu scriptures

Tags: vedas, puranas, rishi, knowledge

Hinduism scriptures describe to origin of people of India  as they were born out of rishis but how do they describe about the origin o people of other countries which are called as mlecchas and yavanas like Greeks and Mesopotamian civilization which evolve at the same time with Indian civilization

Comment: According to the Srimadbhagavatam, when the corpse of Vena was churned by the rishis in search of his heir, the sin of apostasy (committed by him in his lifetime) was extracted out in the form of mlecchas.

Answer (score 1):

One story tells about the origin of *mlecchas* from mouth of Nandini cow.

> And from the froth of her mouth came out hosts of Paundras and Kiratas, Yavanas and Sinhalas, and the barbarous tribes of Khasas and Chivukas and Pulindas and Chinas and Hunas with Keralas, and numerous other Mlecchas.

> [Adi Parva CLXXVII](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc4184.html)

Another story is about their origin from churned body of King Vena. **Matsya Purana 10:7**

[image]